# Section ID disables bootstrap navbar dropdown - Why?

Tags: html, css

As practice, I'm creating a bootstrap html website. I have a navbar, with a few basic buttons and a dropdown. Every nav-link scrolls the page to the related section.

Now, when I use "section id='gallery'" in my code, my dropdown in the navbar doesn't work anymore. When I use any other id, or blank, it works as intended. Note that every other section follows the same principle and is working.

What is causing the problem, and how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help.

```
<!-- Navbar -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#page-top" class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger">Title</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Menu <i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#about" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#gallery" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gallery</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu js-scroll-trigger" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a href="#content1" class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger">Content1</a>
            <a href="#content2" class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger">Content2</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#contact" class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div> <!-- End navbarResponsive -->
  </div> <!-- End container -->
</nav>

<!-- END Navbar -->
```

Faulty ID is below. When I change the "#" to "gallery", the dropdown menu does not work.

```
<!-- Gallery -->
<section id="#" class="content-section text center">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
        <h2 class="headerText">Gallery</h2>
      <!-- Content1 -->
        <section id="content1" class="content-section text center">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                <h3 class="headerText">Content1</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>

        <!-- End Content1 -->

        <!-- Content2 -->

        <section id="content2" class="content-section text center">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                <h3 class="headerText">Content2</h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section> <!-- End Content2 -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!-- END Gallery -->
```

Hope someone can help me understand this better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say every other section follows the same principle and is working. do you mean

```
<a href="#content1" class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger">Content1</a>
<a href="#content2" class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger">Content2</a>
```

because these are links which will link to the section you notate in the href

```
<a href="#gallery" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gallery</a>
```

this is a "button" that shows and hides your drop down menu.  If you would like the drop down menu to work you cannot link to #gallery because a click simply opens and closes the drop down menu.  If you would like to link to the gallery section the a tag will need to be configured the same way content1 and content2 are setup 
you can try something like this

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gallery Menu</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu js-scroll-trigger" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a href="#gallery" class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger">Gallery Section</a>
            <a href="#content1" class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger">Content1</a>
            <a href="#content2" class="dropdown-item js-scroll-trigger">Content2</a>
          </div>
        </li>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and the detailed explanation. I learned something from it and can proceed now!

Comment: You are very welcome Gordon let me know if you need anything else.  Thank you for the answer mark.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not put the id #galery in the href or you could not see the submenu, you should only use the references of the two children items.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this helps a lot!